# Change XMLGregorianCalendar to Date using external binding file (XJB)

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

In my `maven` project, I want all my `datetime` entries should be generated as `java.util.date` instead of `XMLGregorianCalendar`. As you might know `XMLGregorianCalendar` gets generated by default.

We can take example project provided [here](https://github.com/dimitrisli/JaxbShowcase).

Here in the *CustomersOrders.xsd*, you can see attriute `ShippedDate` is of type `dateTime`.

```
<xs:attribute name='ShippedDate' type='xs:dateTime' />
```

To convert its data type into `java.util.date`, I'm following approach provided in documentation [here](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html). i.e. by using external binding file, like:

**Customer.xjb**

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <globalBindings>
    <javaType name="java.util.date" xmlType="xs:datetime"
      parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate"
      printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate"
    />
  </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

Then I mapped `Customer.xjb` file in `pom.xml` like:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- the package for the generated java classes -->
            <generatePackage>com.dimitrisli.jaxb.producedClasses</generatePackage>
            <!-- If the following not specified all xsd in resources are included -->
            <schemaIncludes>
                <include>sampleJaxb/CustomersOrders.xsd</include>
            </schemaIncludes>
            <!-- if you don't want old output -->
            <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
            <!-- if you want verbosity -->
            <!-- verbose>true</verbose -->

            <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>sampleJaxb/Customers.xjb</xjbSource>
            </xjbSources>

        </configuration>


    </execution>
</executions>
```

But when I do `mvn clean install`, I'm still not able to see any difference in `ShippedDate`, which is still being generated as `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Please suggest what am I missing.

*Thank You*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` then you should use `bindingIncludes` instead of `xjbSources` (it's for `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin`).

   ```
   <bindingIncludes>
       <include>sampleJaxb/Customers.xjb</include>
   </bindingIncludes>`
   ```
2. Also, you have to implement a custom adapter for `java.util.Date` like you have seen in the tutorial or convert to `java.util.Calendar`:

   ```
   <javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xsd:dateTime"
   parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
   printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />`
   ```

Hope it helps!